# I need to create two objects in same form (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

so please imagine a form for a car reservation, the form contains both some client information(name, age, city..) and also the reservation informations(start_date, end_date...). 
So obviously, i need to create in the same form a client first, based on the informations and then the reservation which is related to the created client:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
end
```

.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :voiture
end
```

Here is what i did until now(bad way).
The reservation informations start with f.text_field, and the client informations only with text_field(very bad way yes :( )

```
<%= form_for([@voiture, @voiture.reservations.new]) do |f| %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 price_tag">
        <span><%= @voiture.price %>Dhs</span>
        <span class="pull-right">Par jour</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Nom</label>
        <%= text_field :nom, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Nom', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Prenom</label>
        <%= text_field :prenom, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Prenom', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>     
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>CIN</label>
        <%= text_field :cin, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'CIN', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Age</label>
        <%= text_field :age, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Age', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Ville</label>
        <%= text_field :ville, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Ville', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Télephone</label>
        <%= text_field :telephone, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Telephone', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Email</label>
        <%= text_field :email, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Check In</label>
        <%= f.text_field :start_date, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'Start Date', class: 'form-control' %>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Check Out</label>
        <%= f.text_field :end_date, readonly: 'true', placeholder: 'End Date', class: 'form-control', disabled: 'true' %>       
    </div>
</div>

<%= f.hidden_field :voiture_id, value: @voiture.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :prix, value: @voiture.prix %>
<%= f.hidden_field :total, id: 'reservation_total' %>
<%= f.submit "Book Now", id:"btn_book", class: "btn btn-primary wide", disabled: 'true' %>
```

Controller :

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @client = Client.create(client_params)
    @reservation = @client.reservations.create(reservation_params)

    redirect_to @reservation.voiture, notice: "Votre reservation a bien ete cree"
  end

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date, :end_date, :prix, :total, :voiture_id)
  end

  def client_params
    params.permit(:nom, :prenom, :cin, :age, :ville, :telephone, :email)
  end
end
```

I'm sure there is a good and clean way to do that.. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at nested attributes for a good clean solution, here is the doc link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

There is also a gem that can simplify it for you
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form